# Dealing with Objective-C #import dependencies

Tags: objective-c, ios, import, header, circular-dependency

I'm creating a set of files (a library, basically) to accomplish a task which I will use in an iOS app. The library has one public header file that imports all the other header files so that code that uses this library only needs to import the one header. However, that public header also defines an enum that is used internally by most of the other files, so those files need to import the public header. This creates circular dependencies, and I'm getting build errors relating to symbols not being recognized.

What is the right way to handle `#import`s in a situation like this, where a public header file makes a set of library objects available to the public, but the dependent files also need an enum (plus a protocol, actually) defined in the public header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the type definitions into a different header.

Otherwise, you'll have to use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) — but that would really just be hacking around a design flaw.

Comment: Ok. What are the conditions for needing to do this? Will circular imports always cause problems? Or are there other specific situations where things need to be factored out to avoid confusing the compiler?

Comment: @jrdioko: Yeah, it's the circular imports. They're just inherently problematic in Objective-C.